# Conda Update fails with PermissionError

Tags: python, conda, chown

I'm on Mac OS 10.9 and running Python 3.5.2

I tried updating conda

`conda update conda`

but it gave me this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cd/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/cd/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 139, in main
  File "/Users/cd/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 146, in args_func
  File "/Users/cd/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/cli/main_update.py", line 64, in execute
  File "/Users/cd/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 424, in install
  File "/Users/cd/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/plan.py", line 539, in execute_actions
  File "/Users/cd/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/instructions.py", line 149, in execute_instructions
  File "/Users/cd/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/instructions.py", line 92, in LINK_CMD
  File "/Users/cd/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/instructions.py", line 88, in link
  File "/Users/cd/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/install.py", line 634, in link
  File "/Users/cd/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/cd/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d’
```

I searched around and thought the problem was that I needed to `chown` the folder with my user (which is 'cd' in my case):

```
sudo chown -R cd anaconda3
```

Then I tried `conda update conda`, but now it gives a different error:

```
zsh: /Users/cd/anaconda3/bin/conda: bad interpreter: /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/bin/python3: no such file or directory
```

I tried putting `chown`back to root:

```
sudo chown -R root anaconda3
```

but when I tried `conda update conda` it gave me the same "bad interpreter" error.

`where conda` gives `/Users/cd/anaconda3/bin/conda`

I don't know if the problem was the `chown`command or not, but please let me know if you need any more details!

Comment: You have multiple installations of anaconda. 1 is in `/opt` and the other is in your home directory. I would guess that `root` owns `/opt/anaconda*` and `cd` owns anaconda in your home directory. Fix your `PATH` so you don't use the wrong anaconda, then you will be able to update your installation.

Comment: thanks, but there's no folder called `anaconda*` in `opt` an no mention of it in `echo $PATH`

Comment: The shebang in your `/Users/cd/anaconda3/bin/conda` is `#!/opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/bin/python3` as shown in the error message you posted. This is the reason that made me think you have multiple installations of anaconda.

Comment: Ah I see. I think conda did a self-destructive move and for some reason made a change to its shebang when updating, but I don't understand why...

Comment: The shebang is always updated when conda updates files. There is no static shebang. If another user updates his own copy it will have a different shebang than when you update your copy. It happened becuase you ran the update as root when you should have run it as yourself. Consider `user1` and `user2`. The shebang for `user1`'s copy will be `#!/Users/user1/anaconda3/bin/python3` while the shebang for `user2` will be `#!/Users/user2/anaconda3/bin/python3` assuming both of them chose anaconda3 as install directory and both chose python3.

Comment: @alvits : Ah, I see the source of the problem (thought I still don't understand how I ended up with `anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3`). I ended up reinstalling and now it's working, but if you have a less hardcore solution, please consider posting it in this question for other users. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your shebang line in /Users/**USER**/anaconda/bin/conda is broken:

> #!/opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/bin/python

just switch it back to point to the link of your install of Anaconda:

> #!/Users/**USER**/anaconda/bin/python